# Changed behavior of stopLockTask?

Tags: android

I am experiencing a different behavior of Activity.stopLockTask in my app since a few weeks.
I think it started with an Android update (security patch Nov. 2019 for Android 8.0.0 ?) but I am not sure.

The old behavior was, that the app stayed active (visible), when stopLockTask was called.
Now it seems that the lock screen gets active and hides the activity (onPause is called). After unlocking the lock-screen, the app is visible again. But that is not what I need.

The app is for paragliding and I am allowing the user to lock the app temporarily, in order to prevent e.g. leaving the app on accident during flight preparation. The app can be unlocked by the user or even automatically after takeoff. But of course the app should then stay visible in foreground without the need to unlock the phone (Especially as most pilots are wearing gloves).

Does anybody experience the same change and is there a solution to return to the old behavior?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I did find that if you remove your PIN/Fingerprint/Swipe code and leave the device unsecured that this call will return you to the app like you wanted. Once you have a PIN or other security in place Android goes to the lock screen instead.

Comment: No I have no solution. But thanks to your comment I realized, that the changed behavior was indeed caused by securing the device with a PIN. This explains the difference to a lot of other users, which do not have the same problem.